# Secure view (html) files from directly open

Tags: php, kohana

In kohana, this code, secures for example `controller` files from directly open, right?

`<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No Direct Script Access'); ?>`

this code will also write for security `html` files? that is, if we dont need that someone directly open `APPPATH/views/home.php`, we must write in this file:

```
 <?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No Direct Script Access'); ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   ......
   ......
```

?

Comment: Placing them outside the web root is the ideal thing to do.

Comment: I'm not familiar with kohanna, but I think most frameworks place the application code outside the web root and thus it's not accessable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In Kohana access to application/views is restricted in htaccess by:

```
# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
```

So you need not to restrict access to views by putting that code on top.